# Check if MySQL database access granted only after authentication

Tags: mysql, authentication

I work in an organization that is performing the config review of their RDS MySQL Instance.

The review requires me to check if the access to the database is granted only after a secure authentication.

Is there a way to check if this is violated in any way?

Thank You

**Edit: Let us ignore the "secure" part... There must be authentication using the credentials always and for every user**

Answer (score 0):

Depending how "Secure authentication" defined.

Look at [SELECT CURRENT_USER()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connection-access.html) and examine tables for anonymous users.

Is TLS based authentication required? If so examine that in the connection `\s` from mysql client. Attempt to connection without the TLS, or without the client cert, or with a different client certificate as tests of this.

Comment: good clarification. "secure" can end up rather open ended. `CURRENT_USER()` allows the server to show what user you where authenticated which implies the consistency of credentials. Attempt authentication without passwords too.

Comment: So do I have to run SELECT CURRENT_USER() command for each users individually?